# How to move files and folder in same rows based on a pandas/csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, shutil

I have a folder named "My_Videos" inside it has files and a folder named same as the file with some files and also I have a (csv file/df) with the location to move.

I have to move the files and folder based on the output location in csv file. if its location is both it should copy into both the folder else move to respective folder.

Example folder structure

[image]

Output location structure

[image]

csv file with filename,folder name and output folder name

[image]

I have tried this , but i dono how to move folder and files at same time

```
import pandas as pd
import shutil
import os

df = pd.read_csv("my_file.csv")

dest = "Script_Output" 

for _, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['location'] == both:
        source_file = os.path.join("My_videos",row['file_name'])
        dest_file = os.path.join(dest,row['file_name'])
        shutil.copy(source_file, dest_file)
    else:
        source_file = os.path.join("My_videos",row['file_name'])
        dest_file = os.path.join(dest,row['location'],row['file_name'])
        shutil.move(source_file, dest_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

`shutil.copytree(source, dest)` then `shutil.rmtree(source)` will move files and directories from one place to another, and rmtree will remove the old tree